# Managing include paths in Laravel packages

Tags: php, laravel, include-path

I am developing this package where i have to include SDK libraries in my package. Facade and Provider are working fine but when i try to include external libraries(which are not composer loadable), i get Include path errors like this one:

`Failed opening required 'SDK/User.php'`

How do i fix this?

Some details:

1. I have made a package Uploaded SDK files in a folder at Vendor/Package/lib
2. I am using Laravel 4

Please notice that i do not want to autoload this library through composer. I dont think its available for that.

Comment: IIRC the include path is from the path of the index.php, however you can use the helpers to get the correct path? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

Comment: i can correct the include path at one place but there are many other includes, what about them. do i change them one by one?

Comment: You could, however now thinking about it, a better solution would be to use psr-0 autoloading. You can simply add the path to your package and upon `composer dump-auto` it should automatically handle the rest without you having to include anything manually.